# Rabin-Karp constant-time substring hash lookup

Tags: algorithm, hash, modulo, integer-overflow, string-search

Given a string `S[0..N-1]`, I want to be able to get the hash of any of its substrings `S[i..j]` in `O(1)` time, with `O(N)` preprocessing. Here's what I have so far (in Python):

```
BASE = 31

word = "abcxxabc"
N = len(word)

powers = []
prefix_hashes = []

b = 1
h = 0
for i in range(N):
    powers.append(b)
    b *= BASE

    h += (ord(word[i]) - ord('a') + 1)
    h *= BASE
    prefix_hashes.append(h)

def get_hash(i, j):
    if i == 0:
        return prefix_hashes[j]
    return prefix_hashes[j] - prefix_hashes[i - 1] * powers[j - i + 1]
```

It works very well... in Python, where I don't need to worry about possible integer overflow. I want to be able to perform above operations (effectively rewrite the whole algorithm), but modulo some big prime, so that I fit in 32-bit integer arithmetic. Here's what I came up with:

```
MOD = 10**9 + 7
BASE = 31

word = "abcxxabc"
N = len(word)

powers = []
prefix_hashes = []

b = 1
h = 0
for i in range(N):
    powers.append(b)
    b = (b * BASE) % MOD

    h += (ord(word[i]) - ord('a') + 1)
    h = (h * BASE) % MOD
    prefix_hashes.append(h)

def get_hash(i, j):
    if i == 0:
        return prefix_hashes[j]
    return (prefix_hashes[j] - prefix_hashes[i - 1] * powers[j - i + 1]) % MOD
```

But the

```
prefix_hashes[i - 1] * powers_of_base[j - i + 1]
```

part can overflow quite easily for larger `MOD` values. How to go about it?

Comment: So effectively the question is "how do I do modular multiplication without overflow", right?

Comment: @harold Yeah, pretty much. Though I figured the context might be useful - perhaps the problem can be reduced to a simpler one than modular multiplication without overflow.

Comment: Ok, it's quite language-specific actually, even compiler-specific in the case of C++